# Compare list of tuples with list and return list of tuple that not matched

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have list of tuples and a second list. I need to return a list of tuples for which the second item in the tuple does not appear in the second list.

```py
listTuple =  [('IN', 'OS19014'), ('CA', 'OS0001'), ('GB', 'OS0002'), ('CA', 'OS0003')]
normalList = ['OS19014', 'OS0001', 'OS0002']
```

Expected_result:

```py
[('CA', 'OS0003')]
```

Comment: `print([i for i in listTuple if i[-1] not in normalList])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> [lt for lt in listTuple if not lt[1] in set(normalList)]
[('CA', 'OS0003')]
```

Comment: Preferably make `normalList` a `set` first, though, for O(n+m) instead of O(n*m).

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me:

```
listTuple = [('IN', 'OS19014'), ('CA', 'OS0001'), ('GB', 'OS0002'), ('CA', 'OS0003')] 
normalList = ['OS19014', 'OS0001', 'OS0002']
for i in listTuple:
    if i[1] not in normalList:
        print(i)
```